# How do i fix these dependency warnings

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I keep seeing these messages when I launch sbt shell for my play application:

```
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.21 is selected over {2.3.13, 2.4.20}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.5.21 ()        (depends on 2.5.21)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.6.23 ()              (depends on 2.5.21)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.11:2.5.21 ()       (depends on 2.5.21)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.11:10.0.15 ()     (depends on 2.4.20)
```

How do i fix this? Do I need to explicitly set the akka version so it doesn't pick 2.5.21?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to hook up the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) sbt plugin and use the following commands to figure out which components depend on which version of akka-actor

```
sbt <project>/dependencyTree
sbt "<project>/whatDependsOn <organization> <module> <revision>"
sbt <project>/evicted
```

After coming up with the list of component dependencies, you have a few choices:

- Make sure you use the versions of the components (like play) that
  require the same version of akka-actor and akka in general. I usually do it by checking POM files for the libraries in question at https://mvnrepository.com/
- Force sbt to use a particular version of akka (via [dependencyOverrides](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version)). It
  is generally safe to do for different patch versions (as in
  major.minor.patch) for libraries that use semantic versioning
  (https://semver.org/). But it may cause problems for different minor and
  especially major versions if they are not backwards compatible.
- Ignore the conflicts and warnings if they aren't causing problems.
- If you use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create Fat jars, you can use [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) to
  allow multiple versions of akka to live in the same application via
  moving one of them to a different package. It is not always possible though (e.g. when a library loads a class dynamically by name)
- write a custom class loader to dynamically load different versions of a library into separate protection domains. It is not trivial and requires quite a bit of code. I wouldn't recommend it for akka.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is an eviction warning by sbt, you can check the documentation at this [link](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html).

What you could do is to override the dependency used on the sbt file, to avoid runtime errors.

For example:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.21"
```

In this way you're specifying to sbt which version of the library to use.
You can check also the sbt's plugin [dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)to understand all the dependencies inside your project.